# How to type "recursive object of primitives"?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to come up with an interface that will behave similarly to `any` in that properties can be accessed with the dot notation `object.foo.bar` and will describe "recursive object of primitives" that

1. can only have keys of type `string`
2. can only have values of type `Primitive | Primitive[]`

Where Primitive can be defined as `type Primitive = string | boolean | number` and by "nested object" I mean that the value can also be another recursive object of primitives.

So far I've come up with the following:

```js
type Primitive = string | number | boolean

interface IPrimitveObject extends Record<string, IPrimitveObject | IPrimitveObject[] | Primitive | Primitive[]> {}
```

But this fails right on the second level of property access.

```js
const testObject: IPrimitveObject = {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: {
        baz: true
    }
}

testObject.bar.baz //compiler error: "Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | IPrimitveObject | IPrimitveObject[] | Primitive[]'."
```

Which makes sense. But how can one overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you annotate a variable as type `IPrimitiveObject`, that's it's type, and the compiler won't keep track of any particular properties on it that are not known in the definition of `IPrimitiveObject`.

If you want to create an object literal and have the compiler check that it is assignable to `IPrimitiveObject` without actually widening its type to `IPrimitiveObject` and subsequently forgetting all of its specific properties, you can make a generic helper function which only accepts arguments assignable to `IPrimitiveObject`, and returns them unchanged:

```
const asIPrimitiveObject = <T extends IPrimitveObject>(t: T) => t;
```

And you'd use it instead of annotating:

```
const testObject = asIPrimitiveObject({
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: {
    baz: true
  }
});
/* const testObject: {
    foo: string;
    bar: {
        baz: true;
    };
} */

testObject.bar.baz; // type true
```

And if you use something incompatible you should get an error:

```
const badObject = asIPrimitiveObject({
  foo: "bar", // okay
  bar: { baz: { qux: () => 1 } } // error!
//~~~ <-- Type '{ baz: { qux: () => number; }; }' is not assignable to
 //type 'string | number | boolean | IPrimitveObject | IPrimitveObject[] | Primitive[]'.
});
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAzsRAOwHMoAfKQgVyQCMI5ypaB7FgGwgENCBYAKAEJCwBgDMuAY2gBJeMlSYA8rQBWEScCgQAHqMIATXFABKGlnAMAefEWIAaKHMQpgytRq0VnCtxBXqmgDaALpM8q4Y0BQRqFGhAHxQAN5QAL4CUAKSLIT4UFy4PpHugVo4VgAq2noQhsbFiv4emgkAFMAAXFCVAJRQWEnAANwC2bn5ovgBngMFRbFopZ5tyZlQYmzdAOS0XHDb9ut7cN1r-FCXzFwAXt0EVBDrGfxpvaP8APQAVFA5eVopsAZpozutLpsWN1bMJiB8rtdTilwQjrncoA8IPCrmkPmkoN9PmN+ECQcAAHQnSm3YZQT6fDHgaCY4n-fJ7AxkuaFRpLZplVbrSHdABEJxFjnpUBYAGsuCBjvszmjlQBHKg6bptfqDKAARnShqlDDgFgAhAJ6QA-G1QKwAWntPSZUG2qT26NS6s1UG1AyS1DoDFpuPS2ygCGMhBYWkKuAQxEIXFonAxLEy9NAkFdMJITED9EYFFYHG4hCYvOWmgriyrwFC4RccUwoW25IEbw+QA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This nicely solves the case of creating/assigning the object literal.

What if one gets the objects from some IO (think `JSON.parse()`) and wants to annotate it with the `IPrimitiveObject` type so that access to the object is restricted to primitive values. Like `parsedObject.bar` is ok  but `parsedObject.bar()` would rise an error since its properties can not be a function.

Comment: Have you tried it? [Seems to work for me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAzsRAOwHMoAfKQgVyQCMI5ypaB7FgGwgENCBYAKAEJCwBgDMuAY2gBJeMlQYIAeVoArCJOBQIAD1GEAJrigAlTSziGAPPiLEANAKhQ5iFGkyqNWpm4WeKuqawADaALpM8h5KUe6KmBFMVEYQYsIQhgB8UADeUAC+AgKGmuxccNCSLIT4UCwAXK7RCUE+wADcAtW12rQVUDgsAHT9cB1QAPSTsPGBfi3AXsG+FP4ey+1JFItK21AppemEmQJjABQAlFMzhCzaklzs5bScQmJQ56CQLB9jg1gcAAiFgrYBAqAAMkhUAAhABBOBwLggYYIXCI5Egc5ja7QqBA-oALwhwmYFWuuWcUB6dWJg3JcFGXCJE2mswCsTWi02IQWc15Wn2u0SkQohzSGUMAiK-CAA)